# RPM require kernel-devel package of currently installed kernel

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, packaging

I have written an RPM spec that has a requirement for the kernel-devel package.  However, that is satisfied by the installation of *any* kernel-devel package.  How do I specify that the RPM requires the kernel-devel package of the *currently running* kernel version.

For example, our customer could be running 3.10.0-514, however the latest is 3.10.0-693.  If you execute "yum install -y kernel-devel" you get the headers for the latest version, satisfying the "Requires" line in my RPM.  I want to ensure that the headers installed are for 3.10.0-514.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. I've been wrangling with this for years.

You also can't use triggers to watch when `kernel-devel` is installed, because when it is installed, it still won't match the running kernel version.

The solution I have used is to put a custom script into `/etc/init.d/` (or the systemd equivalents) that recompiles the driver on demand each time the OS boots with a potentially-new kernel. And it is smart enough to recognize if the sources aren't there to tell the user to upgrade that as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using scripts in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` and `/etc/kernel/prerm.d` to handle updating the kernel driver anytime the kernel version is changed.  Of course, this depends on `kernel-devel` already being installed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those, but I've been doing it the way I posted since at least RHEL4.

Comment: I discovered it by examining how Oracle installed their virtual box guest additions kernel drivers.  The seemed to be called whenever the `kernel` package is updated.  The `prerm.d` directory contains scripts that are called before the old kernel is un-installed, if that happens, and the `postinst.d` contains scripts that are called after the new kernel is installed.  I found some documentation [here](https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-update-hooks.html).

Comment: For some reason this answer from last December notified me and I can now point to an example - https://github.com/opencpi/opencpi/blob/release_1.3.1/os/linux/driver/opencpi-driver-check